# How to minify handlebars templates using gulp-handlebars

Tags: node.js, gulp, handlebars.js

I have the following handlebars structure:

```
├── gulpfile.js
└── source/
    └── templates/
        ├── view1/
        │   └── template11.handlebars
        └── view2/
            └── template21.handlebars
```

And getting this:

```
└── target/
    └── js/
        ├── view1.min.js    
        └── view2.min.js
```

The question is how to create actual minified precompiled templates. Right now I'm just getting the open precompiled js.

My **gruntfile.js** is:

```
const pump = require( 'pump' )
const rename = require( 'gulp-rename' )
const handlebars = require( 'gulp-handlebars' )

gulp.task( 'build-templates', ( done ) => {

    const views = [
        'view1',
        'view2'
    ]

    let pipe = []

    views.forEach( ( view ) => {
        pipe.push( gulp.src( 'source/templates/' + view + '/**/*' ) )
        pipe.push( handlebars() )
        pipe.push( rename( view +'.templates.min.js' ) )

        // pipe.push( uglify() ) <-- this gives me the error:
        // [13:40:38] GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
        // Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (:) (line: 1, col: 11, pos: 11)"

        pipe.push( gulp.dest( 'target/js' ) )
    } )

    pump( pipe, done )

} )
```

I'm using `pump` just to let node.js know that it has to close the source if a process yields an error while processing the pipe.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realise that I needed to wrap the compiled code as a parameter to `Handlebars.template()`. Clearly pointed out in `gulp-handlebars` docs. :( So the outcome was not a valid js code and uglify couldn't handle it. The solution is:

```
const pump = require( 'pump' )
const concat = require( 'gulp-concat' )
const wrap = require( 'gulp-wrap' )
const declare = require( 'gulp-declare' )
const handlebars = require( 'gulp-handlebars' )
const uglify = require( 'gulp-uglify' )

gulp.task( 'build-templates', ( done ) => {

    const views = [
        'view1',
        'view2'
    ]

    let pipe = []

    views.forEach( ( view ) => {
        pipe.push( gulp.src( 'source/templates/' + view + '/**/*' ) )
        pipe.push( handlebars() )
        pipe.push( wrap( 'Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)' ) ) // <-- this is the key
        pipe.push( declare( {
            namespace: 'MyApp.templates', // <-- get easy access to templates
            noRedeclare: true, // <-- Avoid duplicate declarations 
        } ) )
        pipe.push( concat( view + '.templates.js' ) ) // <-- use concat instead of rename to concatenate several templates
        pipe.push( uglify() ) // <-- done
        pipe.push( gulp.dest( 'target/js' ) )
    } )

    pump( pipe, done )

} )
```